# Server certificate issue for Firebase Crashlytics - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, crashlytics

I have integrated Firebase Crashlytics in my iOS project. App is detected in the Firebase console. But test crash is not tracked in the console.

I followed the step provided by Firebase.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=3&platform=ios

While debugging, I can see some certificate issue for firebase server.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."
```

It also shows
`[Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Completed report submission with id`

I also enabled

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<false/>
```

Log

```
2022-06-05 09:06:29.208678+0530 FirebaseSample[56522:591822] 8.9.1 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Packaged report with id '-----' for submission
2022-06-05 09:06:29.209774+0530 FirebaseSample[56522:591822] 8.9.1 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Completed report submission with id:-----
2022-06-05 09:06:29.426952+0530 FirebaseSample[56522:591824] Task <01C587F9-CDDF-42C8-BB9C-9331D85C9BAF>.<1> finished with error [-1202] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002bac6f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x6000015b03c0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9813, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <01C587F9-CDDF-42C8-BB9C-9331D85C9BAF>.<1>, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x6000015b03c0>, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.}
```

Comment: Do you continue seeing this error? Does it happen after updating the Crashlytics SDK?

Comment: This issue was happening due to some certificate installed in my macOS due t which i was getting this error in Simulators. Working fine in real device.